# How can i stop prepos to create certain compiled scss other than main.scss

Tags: css, sass

[image]

Kindly see the option that I've tried which dont worked out for me.
You can right-click on the file in Prepros and select Disable Auto Compile.

I don't want anything processed except for my "main.scss" file. Is there a way to prevent Prepos from processing certain scss files

Answer (score 1):

For all other files except for `main.scss`, add "_" before the name.
They are called partials. For example `_variables.scss`, `_header.scss` or `_footer.scss` and include them all in the beginning of the `main.scss` file

Comment: [enter image description here][1] .... this is my file structure and in style this is my code........ and i imported all the partials into style.csss .. & stil it is not working @Timppa

Comment: How is it not working? Are you using node-sass or Ruby Sass?

Comment: Im using node-sass . Which one is better to use